# Why do I get "Failed to load PDF document" when I try to open a modified PDF?

Tags: python, django, file, pdf, docx

I am new to web development and trying to create a language translation app in Django that translates uploaded documents. I relies on a series of interconversions between pdf and docx. When my code ouputs the downloaded translated document I get "Error Failed to load PDF document" in my browser. Here is my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from .models import TranslatedDocument
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import docx
from pdf2docx import parse
from docx2pdf import convert
import time #remove

# Create your views here.

@csrf_protect
def translateFile(request) :
    file = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
            uploaded_file_path = fs.path(filename)
            
            file = (converter(uploaded_file_path))
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
        return response
    
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'translator_upload/upload.html', {'form': form})    


def reConverter(inputDocxPath):
    return convert(inputDocxPath)

def translateDocx(aDocx, stringOfDocPath):
    docx_file = stringOfDocPath
    myDoc = docx.Document(docx_file)

    #translation logic



    myDoc.save(stringOfDocPath)
    return reConverter(stringOfDocPath)


    
#stringOfDocPath is used as convert() requires file path, not file object(myDoc)

def converter(inputPdfPath):
    # convert pdf to docx
    
    pdf_file = inputPdfPath
    docx_file = inputPdfPath + '.docx'


    parse(pdf_file, docx_file) #,  start=0, end=3)
    myDoc = docx.Document(docx_file)
    return translateDocx(myDoc, docx_file)
```

I tried returning the file using 'rb' but that didn't work.